# Ansible + Test Kitchen: passing Array data into dependent module

Tags: ansible, test-kitchen

I am trying to set up Ansible + Test Kitchen to test a Galaxy module for Sonatype Nexus.  In order to do this, I want a dependency on `geerlingguy.java` and I'd like to override the default Java version by passing an array `java_packages: ['java-1.8.0-openjdk']`.

The doco for [role dependencies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies) states:

> Role dependencies allow you to automatically pull in other roles when
>   using a role. Role dependencies are stored in the meta/main.yml file
>   contained within the role directory. This file should contain a list
>   of roles and parameters to insert before the specified role, such as
>   the following in an example roles/myapp/meta/main.yml

Examples of how to pass in scalar data follow, but no example of array or hash data follows.

I tried this two ways:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: geerlingguy.java,
      java_packages: ['java-1.8.0-openjdk'] }
```

also all on one line:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: geerlingguy.java, java_packages: ['java-1.8.0-openjdk'] }
```

In this case the `java_packages` seems to be ignored and the default of Java 1.7.0 is used.

I also tried this:

```
---
dependencies:
  - { role: geerlingguy.java,
      java_packages: 
        - java-1.8.0-openjdk }
```

This leads to a syntax error being emitted.

Is it even possible to pass in Array data as I'm trying to do while using Test Kitchen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work another way, using `extra_vars` in `.kitchen.yml`:

```
  extra_vars:
    java_packages: ['java-1.8.0-openjdk']
```